# "reject pile" or "rejected pile"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> In the pantheon of classic modern buildings, Utzon's creation has the status of myth. The myth states that the unknown architect, then in his early thirties, submitted rough sketches to the competition judges, that he ignored most of the rules, that his design was only selected after being plucked at the last moment from the ***reject*** pile by one of the judges, and that the design was unbuildable.

Should the word "reject" be modified to "rejected"? I think that "reject" may not be used as an adjective. Maybe "rejected" is more appropriate.

Comment: See this answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/915/147

Comment: This must perplex many ELLs, for though we usually see *reject* being used as a verb, and *rejection* as a noun, it's not common to see *reject* as a noun. It's not until I saw Jim comment, which gave me an urge to look up *reject* in dictionaries, that I know *reject* can be a noun too!

Comment: But it's pronounced differently as a noun and a verb. To _reject_, the verb, is /rɪ'dʒɛkt/, stressed on the second syllable; but a _reject_, the noun, is /'ridʒɛkt/, stressed on the first syllable. Many English verb/noun pairs are pronounced that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Native:Australian] 
Per @John-Lawler's comment, the verb and noun are pronounced differently.  The **reject pile** (/'ridʒɛkt/ - stress on the first "e") is indicating a **pile of rejects** (noun again, stress on the first e).

If you altered the text to **rejected pile** you would be referring to the pile as a whole, as in **the pile that was rejected**. The author isn't trying to say that the pile itself was rejected, they are saying that it was a pile of rejected entries. A **pile of rejects**, or a **reject pile**.

[FWIW the design clearly was buildable, they built it! I can see it in my window.]